# Justifying the integral identity “$\int \mathrm{e}^{cx} \sin bx\, \mathrm{d}x = \frac{\mathrm{e}^{cx}}{b^2 + c^2}(c \sin bx - b \cos bx)$”

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I suck at integrals. [Here on this Wiki list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_exponential_functions#Integrals_involving_exponential_and_trigonometric_functions), it says that
$$\int \mathrm{e}^{cx} \sin bx \,\mathrm{d}x = \frac{\mathrm{e}^{cx}}{b^2 + c^2}(c \sin bx - b \cos bx),$$
which is easy to check – but how could I have derived that?

Comment: Differentiating the RHS is a fully legitimate way to justify the identity, though it assumes you know the anti-derivative ahead of time. To derive it from scratch, the standard method is repeated integration by parts.

Comment: $\int e^{cx}\sin(bx)=\Im\int e^{cx+ ibx}$ is fast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write $\sin(bx)$ as $\text{Im}\left(e^{ibx}\right)$, so that the LHS is just the imaginary part of $\frac{1}{c+ib} e^{(c+ib)x}$.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to acquire the result without actually differentiating the given integral, then you can use integration by parts twice. For the first application, set $u=\sin (bx)$ and $dv=e^{cx}$. For the second application, set $u= \cos (bx)$ and $dv=e^{cx}$.